# Database: SQL Pagination?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm using MySQL.

I want to limit the amount of rows fetched from the database.  I have a SQL statement that returns 10,000 records which are all relevant to the search.

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM xyzTable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY colA
```

I know how to use the TOP statement to return the TOP x number of rows fetched but how do I fetch rows rows in the middle of the search result, for example, rows 50-100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's [limit clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) makes this easy:

```
SELECT cols
FROM table
LIMIT offset, rowcount
```

In your case:

```
LIMIT 49, 50 -- skip rows 0-49, grab the next 50
```

Answer (score 0):

by doing something like:

`SELECT colA, colB, colC FROM xyzTable WHERE ... ORDER BY colA LIMIT 30 , 40`

30 being the number you want to start on, 40 being now many items you want to see.

Then you can increment these values as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 50, 50
```

> The LIMIT clause can be used to
>   constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes
>   one or two numeric arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM xyzTable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY colA
LIMIT 10, 5
```

The `LIMIT 10, 5` defines the range of results (this would return results 11,12,13,14,15).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM xyzTable
WHERE ...
ORDER BY colA LIMIT 49,50;
```

`LIMIT` row-offset,number-of-rows 
The first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return...