# Consolidated: SQL 2005+ Dynamic Pagination using SET ROWCOUNT or RowNumber()?

Tags: sql-server-2005, pagination, row-number, rowcount

I've a complex SP which applies multiple JOINs and lookup and come complex filters like comma-separated values, etc... On top of it, I've to deploy two complex yet performance-effective features:

**1. Dynamic sorting** but I see its limited - you kno the long/clumsy CASE hierarchy, its strange that experts also agree that this is the only 'best' solution we've got:

[Dynamic Sorting within SQL Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149380/dynamic-sorting-within-sql-stored-procedures)
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=5942

Anyway, I don't expect much on this one for now.

**2. Dynamic pagination** - that is I want the SP to be able to return only X number of records (X = page size) starting from Y (Y = page number). I hope you've got the general idea.

To make it more clear I want to use something available in MySQL & PostgreSQL:

```
[LIMIT { number | ALL }] [OFFSET number]
```

[Database: SQL Pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545203/database-sql-pagination)
http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/queries-limit.html

*Its strange such a simple & basic functionality is NOT available in SQL 2005+ .. or am I wrong (I'd be glad to hear it :-))*

---

I've known two approaches which suite my performance\complexity tradeoff -

**[2.1] Using the 'RowNumber()' feature of SQL 2005** and then applying filter: (I've used it in past)

```
WHERE (Row BETWEEN (@PageIndex-1) * @PageSize +1 AND @PageIndex* @PageSize)
```

But again, this needs creating a temp table or using a WITH clause. This is also explained in:
[Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-ms-sql-server)

**[2.2] I found some new ways.** One of them is using the

```
SET ROWCOUNT
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml

*And they say that overall 2.2 is effective then 2.1. Is it? Also, I wanted to know what happens if two user-requests trigger the same SP twice simultaneously .. I hope the 'SET ROWCOUNT' won't be 'shared' or 'over-written' among simultaneous SP-calls. Pls confirm.
Any other points comparing 2.1 & 2.2 ?*

Comment: IF you're still around, the latter half of your post should really be posted as an answer, not the body of the question

Comment: Thanks but I'm really looking for some expert comments on the same. Thats the reason I've posted my consolidated R&D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe both approaches are good and we can choose to go with what best suits our requirements

---

I've known two approaches which suite my performance\complexity tradeoff -

**[2.1] Using the 'RowNumber()' feature of SQL 2005** and then applying filter: (I've used it in past)

```
WHERE (Row BETWEEN (@PageIndex-1) * @PageSize +1 AND @PageIndex* @PageSize)
```

But again, this needs creating a temp table or using a WITH clause. This is also explained in:
[Row Offset in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187998/row-offset-in-ms-sql-server)

**[2.2] I found some new ways.** One of them is using the

```
SET ROWCOUNT
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml

*And they say that overall 2.2 is effective then 2.1. Is it? Also, I wanted to know what happens if two user-requests trigger the same SP twice simultaneously .. I hope the 'SET ROWCOUNT' won't be 'shared' or 'over-written' among simultaneous SP-calls. Pls confirm.
Any other points comparing 2.1 & 2.2 ?*